# How to tell Configparser to open the config file, that has the same name, as the module, opening it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, configparser

I'm writing a testing framework using Python's unittest. I have separate modules for separate parts of the tested application (part1 - part1.py, part2 - part2.py etc.). I want to create a helper module, which will read configuration settings for each of the modules, with the config file name being the same as the module name (part1.py - part1.conf, part2.py - part2.conf). Config files will reside in the same folder as the modules do.
When I run part1.py I need to tell the tests that config for them is in part1.conf. How do I do that?
This helper module will not necessarily reside in the same folder as the test modules.
I do not want to use nose because I want to have as little external dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def module_config(mod):
    '''Loads the config residing next to the module.'''
    import configparser, os.path
    cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cp.read_file(open(os.path.splitext(mod.__file__)[0] + '.conf'))
    return cp

# load config for some module
import some_module
module_config(some_module)

# load config for current module
module_config(sys.modules(__name__))
```

Comment: Is there any way to automatically determine the module name to not pass the mod parameter to the method?

Comment: @AndriyYurchuk: Sure, I just made it passable to make the function more generic and detach that concern. Just embed `sys.modules(__name__)` in place of `mod` in `module_config`, and remove the `mod` argument.

Comment: That's what creates the problem, actually. If I do what you suggested, cp.read_file will try to read the conf file, which should reside next to the module, containing that function, not the module that calls that function.